# Visual studio container debugging with a remote docker host

Tags: visual-studio, docker, visual-studio-2017

Can you start a container from visual studio but somehow specify to run the container on a remote container host?
My specific scenario - I have an asp.net core app, I added docker support and want to debug using docker when I press F5, however, I would like to use a remote (other computer on the network) installation of the docker host.
This question may not even make any sense as I have probably misunderstood what I'm doing.