# How to develop on remote docker host in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: docker, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, remote-debugging, remote-development

I found an article about [develop on remote docker host](https://code.visualstudio.com/remote/advancedcontainers/develop-remote-host) for visual studio code, But I need something like this for Visual Studio 2022 Enterprise Edition

How to develop on remote docker host in Visual Studio 2022? (Build, Debug, Test)

---

*Some info I hope to be useful*

As you can see in [2. Using DOCKER_HOST environment variable to set up the target engine](https://www.docker.com/blog/how-to-deploy-on-remote-docker-hosts-with-docker-compose) in manual way we can use `DOCKER_HOST` to run docker in remote host, But I do not know how to set this variable in Visual Studio [dcproj](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/docker-compose-properties) for Remote Development and remote Debugging and Remote Testing?

Comment: I found question for debugging step of my question, but this question does not have answer :( https://stackoverflow.com/q/54838418/1539100

Comment: I'm constantly annoyed at the fact that VSC seems to receive better support from Microsoft themselves when compared to Visual Studio.  Even an Enterprise level VS license doesn't offer the same level of functionality that VSC seems to have support for.

Comment: I agree with you, and that is very disappointing. :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The container tools in VS do not support launching containers except through Docker Desktop locally.

The closest work-around for this is to launch the container(s) through the Docker CLI and then attach the VS debugger using the remote container debugging support: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/attach-to-process-running-in-docker-container

Comment: Are you sure any trick or advanced workaround does not exist to meet this requirements? attach to process is very in effective in inner looping development

Comment: There isn't a work-around. You can upvote the suggestion for this: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Allow-Visual-Studio-container-tools-use-/10179694